# NgRx howto map a property value that come from an object angular

Tags: angular, object, mapping, ngrx

am starting to learn NgRX, in angular and I am blocked with tis situation, I don´t know how to map a value that come from an object.

My action.ts

```
export enum AuthActionEnum {
  Login = '[Auth] Login',
}

export const login = createAction(
  AuthActionEnum.Login,
  props<{ userProfile: object; isLoggedIn: boolean }>()
);
```

My state.ts

```
export interface AuthState {
  userProfile: object;
  isLoggedIn: boolean;
}

export const initialState: AuthState = {
  userProfile: null!,
  isLoggedIn: false,
};

export function getInitialState(): AuthState {
  return initialState;
}
```

My Selector.ts

```
import { createFeatureSelector, createSelector } from '@ngrx/store';
import { AuthState } from './auth.states';
export const selectAuthState = createFeatureSelector<AuthState>('auth');

export const getUserProfile = createSelector(
  selectAuthState,
  (state: AuthState) => state.userProfile
);
```

My Reducer index.ts

```
import { createReducer, on } from '@ngrx/store';
import { AuthActions } from '../action-types';
import { getInitialState } from '../auth.states';



export const authReducer = createReducer(
  getInitialState(),
  on(AuthActions.login, (state, action) => {
    return {
      userProfile: action.userProfile,
      isLoggedIn: action.isLoggedIn,
    };
  }), 
);
```

Now I want to get the property value given_name that from the userProfile object, I am stuck .
My Component.ts

```
userName$!: Observable<string>;

    userName$=this.store.pipe(
    select(getUserProfile),
    map((userInfo)=> {
            {
              return userInfo != null 
                ? userInfo['given_name'] <--- ERROR Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"given_name"' can't be used to index type '{}'.
      Property 'given_name' does not exist on type '{}
                : '';
            }
          })
        );
```

What can I do?

Comment: you could create a `UserProfile` interface  to define the profile object structure instead of using a generic `object` type.

Comment: Hello akotech, I could but I don´t know the property name,  the userProfile object is dynamic , I can receive the property give_name, or another.

Comment: have you tried `userinfo.given_name`? sometimes the compiler will moan due to `eslint` rules but works when run